# JQuery conflict with will_paginate ajax pagination

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, conflict, will-paginate

I followed [this](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/ajax-pagination) and got the AJAX pagination to work. But, when I include the JQuery library, it doesn't work. I'm using the jrails plugin but that doesn't help either. Any ideas? Thanks !

Here's the javascript

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
var container = $(document.body)
if (container) {
var img = new Image
img.src = 'images/spinner.gif'

function createSpinner() {
  return new Element('img', { src: img.src, 'class': 'spinner' })
}

container.observe('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.element()
  if (el.match('.pagination a')) {
    el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner())
    new Ajax.Request(el.href, { method: 'get' })
    e.stop()
  }
})
```

}
})

**EDIT**

This is my actual code and it works fine when I don't include JQUERY. 
But I need to use both prototype and JQUERY. Also when I click on one of the page no.s I get this

```
try {jQuery("#testing").html("\n  <div class=\"pagination ajax\"> ......
```

Comment: Did you remove references to the prototype library when you added jQuery? Because the above code is prototype code, it won't work in jQuery. Also did you copy and paste that in? Because if that's your actual code I can't imagine why it would work with no semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include the jquery library, it will assume that all $ calls are calls to jquery (rather than prototype for example).  To prevent this, call the method noConflict on your jquery object immediately after pulling it in.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

When you've done this, $ calls will be ignored by jQuery: it will only respond to "jQuery", ie

```
$("foo").something => prototype
jQuery("foo").something => jQuery
```